# Proving existence of intermediate field of degree 2

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

If $K$ is the splitting field of an irreducible polynomial, which is not solvable by radicals, of degree 5 over Q, show that there is at most one intermediate field, $E$, of degree 2. Prove that if $a, b$ are irrational in $K$ such that $a^2, b^2$ are rational, then $a = rb$ where $r \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I began to think that the galois group is $S_5$ because the polynomial is not solvable by radicals and is irreducible. The only subgroup of index 2 is $A_5$ so I figured this has something to do with it.

For the second part, if I assume the first part, I think the first part of the proof: Consider $\mathbb{Q}(a) = \mathbb{Q}(b)$ because of the first part. So, there exists some automorphism on $\mathbb{Q}$ where $a \to b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Galois group $G$ can be $S_5$ or $A_5$. Both these cases occur.
It cannot be any other group as all other subgroups of $S_5$ are soluble.
As you say $S_5$ has only one index two subgroup. But $A_5$ has none.
A quadratic subextension corresponds to an index $2$ subgroup of $G$.
There is one when $G=S_5$ and none for $G=A_5$. (The quadratic subextension
is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt D)$ where $D$ is the discriminant of the quintic).

If $a^2=A$, $b^2=B$ with $a$, $b\in K-\Bbb Q$ and $A$, $B\in \Bbb Q$ then
$\Bbb Q(\sqrt A)$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt B)$ are quadratic extensions of $\Bbb Q$. We must be in the $G=S_5$ situation, and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt A)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt B)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt D)$. The only rationals with square roots in
$\Bbb Q(\sqrt A)$ are squares of rationals and squares of rationals
multiplied by $A$. So $B=r^2 A$, equivalently $b=\pm r a$, for some $r\in \Bbb Q$.